# С++ вызов переменной класса из статической функции обратного вызова

Tags: c++, qt, функции, callback, static

Вопрос такой: нужно получить доступ к объекту класса `Ui::window` в функции `callback_function()`.
Есть информация, что можно в качестве аргумента функции callback_function передать ей `(void*)this`. Но я не знаю как это сделать. Такую конструкцию `(void*)this` он не принимает. Прошу помощи и выход из сложившейся ситуации.

При выполнении программы:
1) Вызывается функция send_file() класса A;

2) В этой функции вызывается системная функция curl_easy_setopt()
в которой последним аргументом идет указатель на функцию обратного вызова (callback_function)
3) Вызывается сама callback_function (В ней находятся некие данные , которые надо сразу отобразить в Ui::window при выполнении)
4) Никаких псевдонимов в приведенном коде типа: typedef void (*str)(char *c) нету. Только определение в классе A;

```
class A
{
     static void callback_function(void* ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* stream);
private:
     Ui::Window ui;
}

void A::send_file() { curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, callback_function); } //curl_easy_setopt системная функция 


void A::callback_function(void* ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* stream)         // функция обратного вызова в стиле языка "С"
{
//Как в этом месте получить доступ к не статическому объекту Ui::window в класса A?
}
```

Comment: Добавить ключевое слово `friend`, и передавть в функцию указатель на класс.

Comment: Обязательно `void*` использовать?

Comment: Это для примера написано.Там идут аргументы (void* ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* stream)

Comment: Это значит обязательно или нет? -- Не понял

Comment: Аргументы, которые я перечислил - обязательно. В противном случае теряется польза от этой функции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class A
{
public:
    static void callback_function(void* p,int a,char b)
    {
        A* self = static_cast<A*>(p);
        //self->ui;
    }
private:
    Ui::Window ui;
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    A obj;

    A::callback_function(&obj, 1, 'a');

    return 0;
}
```

Дополнено, так как вопрос уточнен:

```
class A
{
public:
    static void callback_function(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata)
    {
        A* self = static_cast<A*>(userdata);
        //self->ui;
    }

    void send_file()
    {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, callback_function);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, (void *)this);
    }

private:
    Ui::Window ui;
    ...
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    A obj;
    obj.send_file();

    return 0;
}
```

Код не компилировал, но работать должно примерно так. Ключевой момент, что значение в `userdata` необходимо задавать с помощью:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, (void *)this);
```

Comment: в месте вызова //self->ui падает в рантайме с ошибкой: Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения.
this было nullptr.

Comment: @Сергей, так добавьте пример как вызывается функция ``callback_function``. очевидно что туда передается неправильно первый параметр.

Comment: Все равно падает во время исполнения.  Почему именно две функции curl_easy_setopt ?   Как вторая функция с (void*)this поймет, как нужно вызвать callback_function?.

Comment: Идея верная. Четвертым аргументом идут входные данные. CURLOPT_READDATA - custom pointer passed to the read callback,  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, &this);

Comment: @Сергей только не надо передавать туда ``&this`` это будет указатель на указатель, нужно передавать ``this``